# gr-modtool does not work in a conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, gnuradio

I must work on Windows 10 then I have chosen to use a conda environment because I found difficult to add OOT modules in GNURadio. The version of GNURadio is 3.8.2, which I installed following the wiki instructions at [this link](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/CondaInstall). I know how to make a simple GNURadio block with an Embedded Python Block while I am new on building OOT modules so, gr_modtool might be the right way to start but, unfortunately, it does not work.

If I activate my environment in the conda terminal, with the command *gr_modtool --help* i get

```
Usage: python -m gr_modtool [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

A tool for editing GNU Radio out-of-tree modules.

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Manipulate with GNU Radio modules source code tree. Call it without options
to run specified command interactively
```

which is not the response shown in [this tutorial](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_Python#3.2.2._Setting_up_a_new_block), since the command list is missing.
Furthermore, with *gr_modtool newmod --help* i get

```
Usage: python -m gr_modtool [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'python -m gr_modtool --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'newmod'.
```

and with *python -m gr_modtool --help* it says *No module named gr_modtool*.

I can't figure out what the problem is. Is there someone who can help me? Are there better ways to make and install new GNURadio modules in my environment?

Comment: Hi Wincio, my advice is to install and use gnuradio in a Linux Virtual Machine. Windows support is not as good as it could be and there are many reasons for this.

Comment: Hi Vasil, I know that gnuradio is better on Linux but i have to work on Windows. By your words, I understand that gr-modtool cannot be used on that os. Maybe I can develop my gnuradio module in Linux by using gr-modtool and add it on Windows, I just have to figure out how

Comment: Hi Wincio, yes it should be possible to use gr_modtool on Linux to just generate cmake scripts, add blocks, etc... and then continue developing on Windows. I haven't used Windows in ages and I don't how difficult would be to fix/port gr-motdool to Windows. Report this problem in gnuradio's mailing list and ask for advice there.